# Python generator instead of class object as reinforcement learning environment

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning

Typical way of using reinforcement learning environments looks like this:

```
env = Environment()
while not env.done:
    state = env.state
    action = choose_action(state)
    env.step(action)
results = env.results
```

But wouldn't it be more pythonic this way:

```
env = Environment()
for state in env:
    action = choose_action(state)
    env.step(action)
else:
    results = env.results
```

What difference does it make? I can see two reasons.

- Less code: in latter example we don't need to worry about `env.done` or keep track of what state we are in, generator will pick up where we left automaticaly
- Easy copy: we can easly duplicate generator in every state to evaluate different strategies

We are looping over object we mutate insided the loop, but since introduction of generator `.send()` method, isn't this sort of acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

The Reinforcement Learning paradigm consists of making repeatively an action in an environment which in turn gives back a new state (and also a reward, some information and a boolean that tells you if the episode is done or not).

Looping over all the possible states of the environment is inconsistent with the *spirit* of RL. Here is an example to illustrate what I mean:

Suppose a robot has to grad a cup of coffee. At each millisecond, the robot receives an image coming from its internal camera. Then, the state space is the state of possible images that its camera can return, right ? Doing this

```
for state in env:
    action = choose_action(state)
    env.step(action)
```

would mean that seeing successively all the possible images that the world could give him, the robot would make a correponding action, which is obviously **not** what you want him to do. You want him to act according to what he has just seen from the previous state to make another new consistent action.

Hence the dynamics from this code definitly makes more sense:

```
while not env.done:
    state = env.state
    action = choose_action(state)
    env.step(action)
results = env.results
```

Indeed it means that, as long as the robot has not grabbed the cup, then he should look at the environment and make an action. Then he looks at the new state and make a new action according to its new observation, and so on.